# How do I find three different strings with hash collisions, without using a brute force approach?

Tags: c#, performance, hashcode

I've seen the following question for a hiring interview:

> How do you find three different strings that have the same hash code in C#?
>
> In other words, given the strings `a`, `b`, and `c`, the following four statements should be true:
>
> ```cs
> a != b
> a != c
> a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode()
> a.GetHashCode() == c.GetHashCode()
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> 1. You shouldn't override `GetHashCode()` and you shouldn't use your own `String` class. Use default .NET implementation.
> 2. You don't need to know the exact implementation of `string.GetHashCode()`.
> 3. One should find the result relatively fast, without having to use multithreading.

I'm a bit puzzled by this one. Is there a way to do it, without actually enumerating strings one by one, which would definitively be very slow, and without checking the actual implementation of `string.GetHashCode()` to figure out how to make collisions?

Comment: Questions like this are asked at interviews to see if folks understand how hashes work.  I think the correct answer is "Hashes are not reversible."  Personally, I'm not a fan of "stump the chump" questions at interviews.

Comment: That said, I did plug your question into ChatGPT4, and it mentioned the "pigeonhole principle" and supplied some sample code.  You can view that [here](https://chat.openai.com/share/2b60de83-22ef-4a01-96a3-0f92620219af).

Comment: What is the standard for relatively fast? `GetHashCode` returns an int, so you must be able to get 3 strings with the same hash after generating 0x200000001 random strings.

Comment: It would take 2^33 + 1 different `string` and compute (and store) their respective hash to be 100% sure to have 3 collisions. If I'm not mistaken. That's huge.

Comment: Maybe they are tricking with "same" vs "equal". Strings compared with `==`/`!=` are often "different".

Comment: @akop what do you mean? We're not talking about operator overloading.

Comment: @gunr2171 `a = "ab" + "c"; b = "a" + "bc"; c = "abc";` They are not the same but matching all four statements.

Comment: WHat if the strings are of a single Unicode character?

Comment: @akop that is not correct: https://dotnetfiddle.net/teUJCi https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjQG4CGATovYgLyIBE9ARp4gGouAY04BuajRwNmPdl3r8hnHqIkwpuGYmHzuq8ZKlGaICAE5SrAIQce5dZpxnLNjsIcncLqwDoA4gCmAC4AEvQAzgAWqAD2ACaBFJ4aTj48ASHh0XGJyY5pFqTCmWGRMQlJ5ClOyEX0pdkVeZRsdo3luVU1ha4dOZUU7O79zd0FOAC+sJNAA You have a Java background - in C# comparing strings with `==` is fine, unlike Java.

Comment: @gunr2171 oh, my bad. Was a long time ago with C#. Thanks for the fiddle.

Comment: The birthday paradox extends to more the two people, see [this Math question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485462/birthday-problem-for-3-people) for the math.

Comment: Related: [Generating three distinct strings with equal hashes using the default hash function in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76349282/generating-three-distinct-strings-with-equal-hashes-using-the-default-hash-funct).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have to generate about 16 million hashes before you find one that occurs 3 times.  This only takes a few seconds and fits into a reasonable amount of memory:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        var dict = new Dictionary<int,String>();
        var pairDict = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<String, String>>();
        String[] result = null;
        while(result == null) {
            String s = rnd.Next(0x40000000).ToString("x8");
            int hash = s.GetHashCode();
            String match;
            if (dict.TryGetValue(hash, out match)) {
                if (s == match) {
                    // already tried this string
                    continue;
                }
                Tuple<String, String> pair;
                if (pairDict.TryGetValue(hash, out pair)) {
                    if (s == pair.Item2) {
                        // already tried this string
                        continue;
                    }
                    result = new String[] {s, pair.Item1, pair.Item2};
                } else {
                    pairDict.Add(hash, new Tuple<String, String>(match, s));
                }
            } else {
                dict.Add(hash, s);
            }
        }
        foreach(String s in result) {
            Console.WriteLine( s + ".GetHashCode() == " + s.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485462/birthday-problem-for-3-people

Comment: May I ask 16 million only reduces the probability of failure to a very low level, but it does not guarantee success, right?

Comment: Well, this code keeps running until it finds an answer... there is an extremely small chance that it will run forever, since there are only 2^30 strings in my test set.  That will not really ever happen.  The average amount of memory used is ~ 500 MB.  About 600MB when you're unlucky.  It's normally distributed, so the odds of requiring more than a couple GB are vanishingly small.  If it takes too long (it won't), then just abort and try it again.

Comment: It's safer to set an upper limit to the size of the dictionaries. Otherwise they might consume more memory than the available RAM, causing [memory paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging), resulting in abysmal drop in performance.